# TinyMCE readonly but with print option enabled

Tags: tinymce

I have this tinyMCE init:

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    readonly:1,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
      toolbar: "print",
readonly:1,
        height : 500
});
```

but with readonly:1 but all the menubar is disabled and I would like to have 
the print option activated.

Answer (score 0):

It's no difficult to have print option active in menu and, otherwise, not allowed to edit the textarea.
Just add the plugin `"noneditable"` in the lists of your plugins.
Add also these two statements in your tinymice.init:

```
content_css : "css/noneditable.css",
noneditable_regexp: /\[\]/g,
```

Delete the `readonly` statement.

With the definition of regexp all text inside "[]" is not editable. You can use any character instead of [].

If you want to put into noneditable all the textarea, use :

```
$foo="&lt;div class='mceNonEditable'&gt;[". $foo."]&lt;/div&gt;";
```